# fastapi-cloudauth | Cognito | JWK problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, fastapi

I've setup my fastapi-cloudauth as the readme describes in [Example (AWS Cognito)](https://github.com/tokusumi/fastapi-cloudauth#example-aws-cognito)
and I'm getting a 401 error with:

```
{
    "detail": "JWK public Attribute for authorization token not found"
}
```

i'm calling my server like:

```
curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/access' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer XXX
```

and my code is basically the hello world example:

```
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi_cloudauth.cognito import Cognito, CognitoCurrentUser, CognitoClaims

app = FastAPI()
auth = Cognito(
    region="eu-xxxx,
    userPoolId="eu-north-xxxx",
    client_id="xxxx"
)

@app.get("/", dependencies=[Depends(auth.scope(["read:users"]))])
def secure():
    # access token is valid
    return "Hello"


class AccessUser(BaseModel):
    sub: str


@app.get("/access/")
def secure_access(current_user: AccessUser = Depends(auth.claim(AccessUser))):
    # access token is valid and getting user info from access token
    return f"Hello", {current_user.sub}


get_current_user = CognitoCurrentUser(
    region="eu-xxxx,
    userPoolId="eu-north-xxxx",
    client_id="xxxx"
)


@app.get("/user/")
def secure_user(current_user: CognitoClaims = Depends(get_current_user)):
    # ID token is valid and getting user info from ID token
    return f"Hello, {current_user.username}"
```

**Notes**:

1. I can't see anywhere to specify my cognito callback URL
2. I've checked the user pool and it works with other frameworks like flask
3. I am able to manually see the cognito-idp url and the token there is valid
4. the server is running on my localhost